# Bypassing Bound mismatch compile error when I checked that T implements Comparable

Tags: java, generics

I'm coding with Java generics.

I currently have to deal with sorting of generic `List`s.

Given `List<T>` where `T` is anything

- If `T` implements `Comparable`, then sort by natural order
- Else, instantiate a proper `Comparator<T>`

I wrote the following code

```
public class MyClass<T> {

    private Class<T> entityClass; //evaluates to T. Always!

    protected List<T> orderBy(List<T> list, Collection<ItemSorting> order)
    {
        if (order == null)
            if (!Comparable.class.isAssignableFrom(entityClass))
                throw new RuntimeException("Entity " + entityClass.getSimpleName() + " not sortable");
            else
                Collections.sort(list);
        else
        {
            Comparator<T> comparator = ...; //my Reflection-based comparator

            Collections.sort(list, comparator);
        }

        return list;
    }
}
```

The compilation problem lies in `Collections.sort(list);`. And the error is:

```
Bound mismatch: The generic method sort(List<T>) of type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (List<T>). The inferred type T is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <T extends Comparable<? super T>>
```

Obviously, I know that I cannot sort a `List` without a `Comparator` if `T` itself is not `Comparable`. But since I have checked that, I'm sure that the sorting **is** possibile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Casting the `List<T>` to a generic `List`, though rising warnings (`unchecked` and `rawtypes`) solves the compilation problem.

```
Collections.sort((List)list);
```